# Checking all non-numerical entries in a data.frame column and delete or substitute

Tags: r, select, dataframe, subset

I'm facing a specific empirical problem. I have a dependent variable in a data.frame column. I can easily delete all NAs and all non-numeric terms (unfortunately it was an open text design question). But there are some strings and other information in those non-numeric entries which I would like to check by hand (for possible imputation).

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), B=c("40g", "< 2", "thx", "about 1", "1-2", "1/2", 3, 2.3, "two")))

  A       B
1 1     40g
2 2     < 2
3 3     thx
4 4 about 1
5 5     1-2
6 6     1/2
7 7       3
8 8     2.3
9 9     two
```

I think there is no specific routine to list all non-numerical entries and ask me for each case whether I want to keep it or substitute another value for this entry. But maybe this is at least possible for the entire column?

In the end I like to get the following structure:

```
  A   B
1 1 0.4
2 2  NA
3 3  NA
4 4 1.0
5 5 1.5
6 6 NA
7 7 3.0
8 8 2.3
9 9 2.0
```

Because there are extremely different entries, I need to judge for each case whether I can assume a numerical value (sometimes average). For example I calculate the average of information "1-2" or "between 1 and 2" and I convert different units like "40g" into "0.4" but ignore all nonsense strings "banana" as well as all ambiguous information ("<2").

The reported measure is quantity consumsed. So there are no negative units. Sometimes it's gram or kilogram.

Thank you very much!

**Update**

Thank you so much Tensibai for specifying my question! Here's how I can create a list of problematic non-numericals which may or may not be potential candidates for imputations:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), B=c("40g", "< 2", "thx", "about 1", "1-2", "1/2", 3, 2.3, "two"))
df$B <- as.character(df$B)
df$B[is.na( as.numeric(df$B) ) ]
[1] "40g"     "< 2"     "thx"     "about 1" "1-2"     "1/2"     "two"
```

Now I want to create something like a vector, e.g.

```
(0.4, NA, NA, 1, 1.5, NA, 2)
```

which should substitute the before listed entries at their very position in my original data.frame. I don't need any function for the transformation step, but will do this by hand!

Comment: 1-2 would make more sense to be -1, and how 1/2 became 1.5? Isn't this .5? And why 40g is .4? What would be 40m? What is the measuring unit here? Is it always kg?

Comment: How many other patterns do you have?

Comment: Those are "portions" consumed. 100 gram is defined as a portion, sometimes people report grams instead of portions. There are no "40m" entries (I hope)! All kinds of different entries ...

Comment: Why did 1/2 become NA ?

Comment: You will have to code a rule for each entry `table(df$B)` will give you an idea of how big your headache will be.

Comment: Because I was too fast an this issue. The before comment was right, I cannot be sure to interpret 1/2 as either 0.5 or 1.5. In the end the decision rule will no longer be that arbitrary  ;) I'm sry. But the question refers to any arbitrary decision rule.

Comment: Just to be sure: a function asking you interactively what to do when there's no obvious case would be enough ? (I.e: asking what to do for entry 'two' is acceptable ?)

Comment: I'm not sure whether a function is necessary. I think this problems concerns cases by the dozen (but not hundreds). If I only find a way to show all non-numericals in a vector (save the reference row-number) and could create a substition vector for those special rows would be perfect.

Comment: So, if the output is the vector of 'non-guessables', it's enough ? (replacing it is kinda easy at end)

Comment: Non-guessables would be great (as intermediate output). ATM my is.numeric command isn't even working anymore. I'm totally confused :(

Comment: Anyone who will dare answering this, will be handling infinite follow up questions from the OP, controversial voting and hundreds of edits, which will probably end up in deletion of the answer completely. As it stands now, this is way too broad and not well defined.

Comment: So please, give me a moment to adjust my question. I don't now why my code isn't working anymore. I already was able to list all my non-numericals. But it isn't working anymore. That's why I cannot state my question of "changing" those - because there're just gone ://

Comment: I assume you nedd to `df$B <- as.character(df$B);` (to remove the factor) and then you're looking to `df$B[is.na( as.numeric(df$B) ) ]` (there's a warning but it's intended)

Comment: @Tensibai That's perfect. Now I have a list of my problematic cases (ca. 40 out of 1000). You said the replacing at the end might be very easy. If you can help once more me on this point, my question is answered :) thx !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a loop and readline to create the new vector like this:

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), B=c("40g", "< 2", "thx", "about 1", "1-2", "1/2", 3, 2.3, "two")))
df$B <- as.character(df$B)

myscan <- function(x) {
 new <- vector("numeric",length(x))
 for(i in seq_along(x)) {
   new[i] <- readline(sprintf("Non numeric entry '%s' new value to set: ",x[i]))
 }
 as.numeric(new)
}

# get the entries 
notNum <- is.na( as.numeric(df$B) )
# Loop and ask for updates
df$B[notNum] <-  myscan(df$B[notNum])
```

When run it gives:

```
> df$B[notNum] <- as.numeric( myscan(df$B[notNum]) )
Non numeric entry '40g' new value to set: 0.4
Non numeric entry '< 2' new value to set: na
Non numeric entry 'thx' new value to set: ba
Non numeric entry 'about 1' new value to set: 1
Non numeric entry '1-2' new value to set: 1.5
Non numeric entry '1/2' new value to set: na
Non numeric entry 'two' new value to set: 2
```

Then we return the column to numeric state:

```
df$B <- as.numeric(df$B)
```

And we get the new data frame:

```
> df
  A   B
1 1 0.4
2 2  NA
3 3  NA
4 4 1.0
5 5 1.5
6 6  NA
7 7 3.0
8 8 2.3
9 9 2.0
```

Comment: This is sooo amazing! You made my day! At the end I have to change this one column with "df$B <- as.numeric(df$B)" in order to make further calculations. I tought of doing it by hand, but your function is such a useful tool for me. It will save me days and days of time!

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I wrote in the answer, turn back to numeric once replacement is done...